# Can you save Recyclerview position to a variable?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am working on a simple eReader app. One of the things I need to do is save the position the user was at last for each ebook. To display the ebook I am using a Recyclerview for the text (it's just a Recyclerview displaying raw text).

I am not very familiar with Recyclerview, but from what I've read it seems saving the scroll position is possible. However, in most examples it shows it being used in a save/restore state context. What I need to do is save the position for each book.

Is it possible to save the position into some variable which can be loaded when the book is opened again? The way I am handling the books is using a custom object that contains the title and the actual text of the book. I would like to save the position into a variable inside these custom objects, for each individual book. So that when that object's text is displayed, it will go back to the last position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the recycler view position by:

```
GridLayoutManager layoutManager = ((GridLayoutManager)mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager());
int recyclerPosition = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
```

and then you can save the position in sharedpreferences

and in onCreate or onResume you can call:

```
mRecyclerView.setPosition(recyclerPosition);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'm not sure if using Recyclerview just for the mere purpose of displaying text is right. Recyclerview is used for more sophisticated uses like displaying lists with custom views etc. You can directly use TextView for this purpose.

What you can do it, create a ScrollView, then under it create one child vertical Linear Layout and then keep the TextView as child of this LinearLayout.

Something like this :

```
 <ScrollView
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"> 

       </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Now, to know the position of the ScrollView, you can use `getScrollY()` on your `ScrollView`

Answer (score 0):

```
holder.lay_item.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if(holder.lay_item.isSelected()) {
                    holder.lay_item.setSelected(false);
                    foodAlergies.get(position).setFlag(false);

                } else {
                    holder.lay_item.setSelected(true);
                    foodAlergies.get(position).setFlag(true);
                }

                String type="";
                int child_position=-1;

                itemClickListener.recyclerViewClicked(type,position,child_position);



            }
        });
     public void recyclerViewClicked(String type, int position, int child_position) {
     // String  prodctid = searchdata.get(position).getId();

    }
```

happy coding